# AngularJS menu - remember which item was clicked and set active

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have a menu, but unfortunately, when I click an item, it's not being remembered (i.e. highlighted gray).

[image]

```
    <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl as ctrl">
      <md-menu>
        <md-button aria-label="Menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </md-button>

        <md-menu-content width="4" ng-model="selected">


          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button href="home" ria-label="Home">
              Home
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
          <md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button href="about" ria-label="About">
              About
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
          <!--<md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>-->
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button href="areas" ria-label="Areas">
              Speciality Areas
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button href="clients" ria-label="Clients">
              Clients
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button href="blog" ria-label="Blog">
              Blog
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button href="latest" ria-label="Latest">
              Latest
            </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>




        </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>
   </div>
```

As you can see from the screenshot above, I have clicked "Clients" already, I am on the "clients" page, yet the "Clients" item isn't highlighted!!!

Can anyone share some tips on how to do this in the most lightweight manner?

Here's my controller javascript:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('DropdownCtrl', DropdownCtrl);


  function DropdownCtrl($scope, $meteor, $mdDialog) {
    var vm=this;

    vm.date = new Date();

    var originatorEv;
    vm.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
      originatorEv = ev;
      $mdOpenMenu(ev);
    };

    vm.selected = function(ev){
      console.log(ev);
    }

  };
})();
```

Comment: Dear Eamorr, did my solution helped solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 - The ugly (but fast) one

In order for your menu to be highlighted, you need to tell it to highlight. For this, you need:

1. Define a css class for highlighted menu button (e.g. `.is-active`)
2. Define a function that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether a path that you've sent is the current page
3. In your html, assign the css class defined in point 1 depending on what the current path is

For instance:

```
<md-button href="clients" ng-class="{'is-active': vm.isCurrentPage('/clients')}">
  Clients
</md-button>
```

And the javascript function:

```
function isCurrentPage( path ) {
  return path === $location.path();
}
```

## Solution 2 - The good (but a bit more complex) one

Save the state of your menu in a service. Thus, you will have access to the state of your application (the current page, previous pages, etc.) from anywhere in your app. The benefit from this approach is that services are singletons in angular and any change that you do to the menu will affect the same object (menu service), thus the state of your app will always be synchronized.